# how to call a parameterized constructor of class A inside of class B? C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare a new obj and call the constructor of class B, all inside of class A.

I get two errors......

> error: expected identifier before numeric constant

and

> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

```
class A {
   public:             
   class B {

      private:
      int num;

      public:
      B(int in)
      {
          num = in;
      }

   };

   B obj(7);  // here is the problem

};
```

It seems like this line `B obj(7);` is giving me the errors.

Comment: Try `B obj{7};` or `B obj = 7;`

Comment: I tried B obj{7}; it worked for my test code, but when I try to print out num .... obj.printFunc();.... I get error: ‘obj’ does not name a type. what is that doing?

Comment: See the answer to the linked question, it explains it in some depth.

Comment: What would `obj.printFunc();` do? `obj` is of type `B`, which doesn't have a `printFunc` method. Anyway, that should be a separate question.

Comment: it's a fictitious accessor that would cout the num data member. sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: Write it, make it real, then see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Before C++11, it is possible to have only member declarations in the class scope. To initialize them, one has to use the class's constructor(s).

```
class A {
   public:             
   class B {

      private:
      int num;

      public:
      B(int in)
      {
          num = in;
      }

   };

   A() : obj(7) {}

   B obj;

};
```

Member initializers became available since C++11:

```
class A {
   public:             
   class B {

      private:
      int num;

      public:
      B(int in)
      {
          num = in;
      }

   };

   B obj{7}; // or: B obj = 7;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

as @cigien pointed out:

```
class A {
public:
    class B {

    private:
        int num;

    public:
        B(int in)
        {
            num = in;
        }

    };

    B obj{7};  

    // B obj = 7;  
    // can be written like that as long as the constructor is not "explicit"

};
```